# Calculate nXn in matrix - R?

Tags: r

I converted an image into a 100x100 matrix of 0's and 1's.

An ntile is nXn selection. I am trying to calculate how many 2 tiles there are in the matrix with the 2 left most entries are 1 and the two most right entries are 0.

Eg

```
[1 0]
[1 0]
```

Any idea on how to start this?. I am quite new to R. Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subset all chunks of larger matrix with dimensions equal to that of `ntile` and then check if all the elements of the chunk match the corresponding elements of `ntile`.

```
#Data
set.seed(1)
m = matrix(sample(1:0, 16, TRUE), 4)
m[3, 4] = 0

ntile = rbind(1:0, 1:0)

n = dim(ntile)

ans = t(sapply(n[1]:nrow(m), function(i){
    sapply(n[2]:ncol(m), function(j){
        temp = m[(i- nrow(ntile) + 1):i, (j - ncol(ntile) + 1):j]
        all(temp == ntile)
    })
}))
ans
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE

sum(ans)
#[1] 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution if I understood your question correctly:

```
set.seed(123)

size <- 4
m <- matrix(sample(0:1, 12, replace = TRUE), size-1, size)
m <- rbind(m, c(0,0,1,0))

sum(m[1:(size-1),1:(size-1)] == 1  & m[2:size,1:(size-1)] == 1 &
      m[1:(size-1),2:size] == 0 & m[2:size,2:size] == 0)
```

**Input**

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    1    0
[2,]    1    1    1    1
[3,]    0    0    1    0
[4,]    0    0    1    0
```

**Output**

```
# 1
```

You can make sure that the number of 2 tiles is 1.

Comment: Thank you very much